# Create a form dynamically with jquery and submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a form dynamically via jquery and submit it to a PHP file. This creates the form but nothing happens when i click the submit button. What is going wrong here ?

Method i am using to create a form dynamically is :-

```
    $('#share').append("<form action='sharer.php' method='POST'/>");
    $('#share').append("<div class= 'appm'>Save this/div/>");
    $('#share').append("<input type='text' placeholder='Name' name='routename' id='rname'/>");
    $('#share').append("<input type='text' placeholder='description' id='rdescription' name='routedescription' class= 'address'/>");
    $('#share').append("<input type='text' placeholder='tags' id='tags' name='routetags'  />");
    $('#share').append("<br><input type='submit' id='savebutton' value = 'Save' />");
    $('#share').append("</form>");
```

Comment: First of all: **NEVER** put a space between your HTML attribute and their value. Some browsers won't interpret anything at all because of this. Try using double quotes too.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Solution

You are **appending all the content** that you add **to the parent element**, so they **won't get inside the form** itself. Way to fix this:

```
   $("#share").append('<form action="sharer.php" method="POST">');
   $("#share form").append('<div class="appm">Save this</div>');
   $("#share form").append('<input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="routename" id="rname"/>');
   $("#share form").append('<input type="text" placeholder="description" id="rdescription" name="routedescription" class="address"/>');
   $("#share form").append('<input type="text" placeholder="tags" id="tags" name="routetags"/>');
   $("#share form").append('<br><input type="submit" id="savebutton" value="Save" />');
```

You don't need to append a closing tag for the form after that.

### [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MVXXX/1/)

---

### [Performance-wise](http://jsperf.com/optimization-test-append-jquery): Pure JavaScript

(jsperf link up there)

If you really want a good performance solution, go for pure JavaScript code:

```
var div = document.getElementById('share');
var form = document.createElement('form');
form.setAttribute('action', 'sharer.php');
form.setAttribute('method', 'POST');
/*-----------*/
var appm = document.createElement('div');
appm.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Save This'));
appm.setAttribute('class', 'appm');
/*-----------*/

var input1 = document.createElement('input');
input1.setAttribute('type', 'text');
input1.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Name');
input1.setAttribute('name', 'routename');
input1.setAttribute('id', 'rname');

var input2 = document.createElement('input');
input2.setAttribute('type', 'text');
input2.setAttribute('placeholder', 'description');
input2.setAttribute('name', 'routedescription');
input2.setAttribute('id', 'rdescription');
input2.setAttribute('class', 'address');

var tags = document.createElement('input');
tags.setAttribute('type', 'text');
tags.setAttribute('placeholder', 'tags');
tags.setAttribute('name', 'routetags');
tags.setAttribute('id', 'tags');

var submit = document.createElement('input');
submit.setAttribute('type', 'submit');
submit.setAttribute("value", "Save");
submit.setAttribute('id', 'savebutton');

form.appendChild(input1);
form.appendChild(input2);
form.appendChild(tags);
form.appendChild(submit);

div.appendChild(form);
```

Comment: I dont need to add </form> in the end ? is that what you said in the last line ?

Comment: @user1263375 Yes. Since you `append()` the content INSIDE tags, those tags are created automatically (the opening and closing tags). It's the same behavious as if you would do `var p = document.createElement("p"); document.createElement("form").appendChild(p);`. This would be the output: `<form><p></p></form>`

Comment: One more thing. What if i want to add some feilds which are hidden. I mean with default values but not visible to the user. How to add those to this form ?

Comment: You do those like any other input: `$('#share form').append('<input type="hidden" value="Whatever"/>');` an input with the **type** hidden is like a regular **text** input, but it is not shown in the content flow.

Comment: I fixed a small typo in your code, I'll leave the fiddle updating to you, if you choose to update it, but the typo is there too, just an FYI. ;-)  The typo was right after `Save this`.  

GOOD ANSWER!

Comment: @SpYk3HH Thank you sir, I just copied the code from the OP, which also contained this typo. Updated the JSFiddle :).

Comment: Vapor is small, but just not as well-factored or documented as jQuery. I've also noticed they have yet to update their speeds against jQuery since it's been optimized and completely made over (ie. 1.72). Vapor is alright, but I just find it to be a lot more work than the already well established, well documented and well supported jQuery

Comment: Curious how your proposed 40 lines of code is better "*performance*" than my proposed 2nd example at only about 15 lines?

Comment: @SpYk3HH Your code is [**~88% ±10% slower**](http://jsperf.com/optimization-test-append-jquery/3) than mine.

Comment: lol, first, ur math is off in your comparison. Not much, but off. Second, you're only looking at "speed", which is a ***dead argument*** these days. Third, you're comparing *speed* of jQuery mark-up to *speed* of vanilla, duh!? You've still yet to explain why it *performs* any better? Performance isn't just about *speed*. At least not these days. If you want absolute speed, minify everything. Otherwise, you also have to take into account *readability*, *functionality*, *ease of use*, *ease of maintenance*, and even pure *simplicity*. Thus, I still don't see how your's "*performs*" any better.

Comment: And let me rephrase one thing, Speed is a ***dead argument*** on simple small scale projects like most *any* basic website. The only time speed really becomes an issue these days (thanks to new standards that have been around for several years) is when you look at doing something more integrated. Such as a JS based *game* or *tool* which requires mass amounts of computations and calculations in order to create a user visible resolution. Otherwise, it's a dead issue. And if speed is your issue, I advise [**asmjs.js**](http://asmjs.org/)

Answer (score 15):

First of all, There is way easier way to write that. Second, you're not appending anything to the form. I would rewrite that one of 2 ways.

### [Example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/rLDbQ/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#share').append(
            $('<form />', { action: 'sharer.php', method: 'POST' }).append(
                $('<div />', { class: 'appm', text: 'Save this' }),
                $('<input />', { id: 'rname', name: 'routename', placeholder: 'Name', type: 'text' }),
                $('<input />', { class: 'address', id: 'rdescription', name: 'routedescription', placeholder: 'description', type: 'text' }),
                $('<input />', { id: 'tags', name: 'routetags', placeholder: 'tags', type: 'text' }),
                $('<br />'),
                $('<input />', { id: 'savebutton', type: 'submit', value: 'Save' })
            )
        )
    })
</script>
```

With Example 1, you may need to asign `events` dynamically. Such as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(document).on('click', '#share form input[type=submit]', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            /*  do work */
        })
    })
</script>
```

### [Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/w7PpL/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var $form = $('<form />', { action: 'sharer.php', method: 'POST' }),
            frmSave = $('<div />', { class: 'appm', text: 'Save this' }),
            frmRName = $('<input />', { id: 'rname', name: 'routename', placeholder: 'Name', type: 'text' }),
            frmRDesc = $('<input />', { class: 'address', id: 'rdescription', name: 'routedescription', placeholder: 'description', type: 'text' }),
            frmRTags = $('<input />', { id: 'tags', name: 'routetags', placeholder: 'tags', type: 'text' }),
            frmButton = $('<input />', { id: 'savebutton', type: 'submit', value: 'Save' });

        $form.append(frmSave, frmRName, frmRDesc, frmRTags, $('<br />'), frmButton).appendTo($('#share'));
    })
</script>
```

With example 2, you can make later use of the variables (even make them global if needed) and make changes using variables, such as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        frmButton.on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            /*  do work */
        })
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

JQuery will never allow you to put a tag without closing it. So now, your code create a form and appen elements after the form (not inside).

But you can create a form, save it in a var and append your things into the var.

```
var form = $('<form/>', {action : 'sharer.php', method : 'POST'}).appendTo('#share');
form.append("<div class= 'appm'>Save this</div>");
form.append("<input type='text' placeholder='Name' name='routename' id='rname'/>");
form.append("<input type='text' placeholder='description' id='rdescription' name='routedescription' class= 'address'/>");
form.append("<input type='text' placeholder='tags' id='tags' name='routetags'  />");
form.append("<br/><input type='submit' id='savebutton' value='Save' />");
```

This is also optimal since you are caching the form, not creating a jQuery object for each append!

Working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Lb8BY/ (append to body)

Answer (score 1):

@Karl-André Gagnon - think outside the box :)

```
        //Start
        var $positionTitle = $('.fac_ad_apply_title').text(),
            $departmentTitle = $('.fac_ad_apply_appt_org').text();
            $requiredText = $('.fac_ad_apply_required').text();

        //Creating variables - contact information
        var $form = $('#user_response'),
            $formAttr = $form.attr(),
            $firstName = $('#first_name').attr(),
            $middleName = $('#middle_name').attr(),
            $lastName = $('#last_name').attr(),
            $suffixName = $('#suffix').attr(),
            $email = $('#email').attr()

    //Form
        $('#fac_ad').before(
            $('<h1 />').append($positionTitle),
            $('<h3 />').append($departmentTitle),
            $('<p />').append($requiredText),
            $('<form />', $formAttr).append(

                //Contact Information
                $('<div class="form-group" />').append(
                    $('<label for="">First Name</label>'),
                    $('<input class="form-control" />', $firstName)
                ),
                $('<div class="form-group" />').append(
                    $('<label for="">Middle Name</label>'),
                    $('<input class="form-control" />', $middleName)
                ),
                $('<div class="form-group" />').append(
                    $('<label for="">Last Name</label>'),
                    $('<input class="form-control" />', $lastName)
                ),
                $('<div class="form-group" />').append(
                    $('<label for="">Email address</label>'),
                    $('<input class="form-control" />', $suffixName)
                ),
                $('<div class="form-group" />').append(
                    $('<label for="">Suffix/Degree(s)</label>'),
                    $('<input class="form-control" />', $email)
                )
            )
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

I would submit the form using the jQuery `on()` method, it allows you to bind events to dynamically created elements anchored by static elements such as the body tag

```
$("body").on("submit", "#share form", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

In your case, if the form isn't submitting I would use ajax to submit the form instead of the standard form submit. You could even execute a javascript page refresh after its done if you want a refresh to happen

```
$("body").on("submit", "#share form", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // Grab all form data
    var formInputData = $(this).serializeObject();
    // send form data to php file in $_POST array
    $.post("sharer.php", formInputData, function(data){
        // log errors or anything that is echoed back from php file
        console.log(data);
        // refresh the page
        window.location.reload();
    });
});
```

Don't forget to put it all in a document ready function and have the jQuery library included in your HTML head tag

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").on("submit", "#share form", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        // Grab all form data
        var formInputData = $(this).serializeObject();
        // send form data to php file in $_POST array
        $.post("sharer.php", formInputData, function(data){
            // log errors or anything that is echoed back from php file
            console.log(data);
            // refresh the page
            window.location.reload();
        });
    });
});
```

jQuery include example

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```