# Submitting a dynamic form in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am dynamically creating a form in Jquery, and this form needs to submitted using AJAX. I'm probably doing something stupid, so your help would be greatly appreciated.

I am dynamically creating a form when a link is clicked:

```
$('.edit_item').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('table').wrap("<form id='update_project' name='update_project' method='POST'>");
    var input_name = $(this).closest('tr').find("td:eq(0)");
    var input_submit = $(this).closest('tr').find("td:eq(1)");
    input_name.html("<input type='text' id='update_name' name='update[]' value='"+input_name.text()+"' />");
    input_submit.html("<input type='submit' value='update' id='update_submit' name='update_submit' />");
});
```

When the form is submitted:

```
$('#update_project').live("submit", function(e){      
    e.preventDefault();        
    $.post('project/update', $(this).serialize(), function(data){
        $('#complete_msg').html(data);
    });
    $('.update_submit').css('background', '#c9c9c9');
});
```

Unfortunately, the page is refreshing (it shouldn't), and there is no return.

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431760/create-a-form-dynamically-with-jquery-and-submit

Comment: @NishuTayal Unlikely - the form wraps the table, the elements are inside.

Comment: IF you don't round trip (submit) you are going to have to "unwrap" to prevent duplicate ID of "update_project".  Same duplicate ID issue for the inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change the submit to a button:

```
 input_submit.html("<input type='button' value='update' id='update_submit' name='update_submit' />
```

and the event, live is depreciated (http://api.jquery.com/live/):

```
$('#update_submit').click(function(e){      
    $.post('project/update', $('#update_project').serialize(), function(data){
        $('#complete_msg').html(data);
    });
    $('.update_submit').css('background', '#c9c9c9');
});
```

Comment: `$('#update_submit').click(` ... `$(this).serialize()` - Serialize the button?

Comment: Be sure you add the `$('#update_submit').click(function(e){` handler AFTER you create that element or it will not fire.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if my answer is too basic - your coding is quite advanced but you missed a couple of things. Better for me to be too pedantic rather than not provide enough info to  immediately resolve your problem.

The page is refreshing when user clicks the `update` button because you are using the .submit method. If you do not want the form to refresh, use Stephen King's answer above to:

- change the `<input>` type to `type="button"`, then
- use the `("#yourbuttonID").click()` event to $.post your form data.

Also as SK said above, note the `.live()` is deprecated, so simply switch for `.on()`

Try this:

```
$('.edit_item').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('table').wrap("<form id='update_project' name='update_project' method='POST'>");
    var input_name = $(this).closest('tr').find("td:eq(0)");
    var input_submit = $(this).closest('tr').find("td:eq(1)");
    input_name.html("<input type='text' id='update_name' name='update[]' value='"+input_name.text()+"' />");
    input_submit.html("<input type='button' value='update' id='update_submit' name='update_submit' />");
});

$(document).on("click", "#update_submit", function(e){
    $.post('your_processor_filename.php', $(this).closest('form').serialize(), function(data){
        $('#complete_msg').html(data);
    });
    $('.update_submit').css('background', '#c9c9c9');
});
```

Note that you need the `.closest('form')` selector to get your form data serialized.

I would also use `$(document).on('click'...` to ensure your injected button is found.

I am unfamiliar with the type of file to which you are sending the form data for processing, but `project/update` is not a familiar file type to me. Ensure that it is a page of code that can process your data, such as a .PHP file. See my example above -- or, better yet...

By way of example, create a .PHP file named 'your_processor_filename.php' (i.e. the filename I am referencing in the code I typed above). Put it in the same folder and type the following at the top:

```
//echo 'Got to the PHP side';

echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
die();
```

That will echo back what you sent and allow you both to see the data going through and confirm that the AJAX is working.

Note that your HTML must contain a div with the ID `complete_msg` to see the return message, such as:

```
<div id="complete_msg"></div>
```

Comment: PHP? seems not to be PHP to me for the post, why change that?